# Trying to make my menu more responsive using the @media code

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I have this code

```
@media all and (max-width: 1400px) and (min-width: 951px;){
    #navi2 {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 950px;){
    #navi2 {
        display: initial;
    }
    #navi{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

#navi{
    // MENU CODE
}
```

I wanted to do this to make it kinda responsive, so that navi2 could open if there is a smaller screen. And navi is for a bigger screen.

EDIT: The issue is that the code does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue? what is the question?

Comment: The code does not work for some reason!?

Comment: It seems like you have a semicolon in your media query `(min-width: 951px;)` Just remove it.

Comment: Remove semicolon then it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/3gksp002/

Comment: @PDKnight THANKS IT FIXED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a semicolon in your query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1400px) and (min-width: 951px;){
```

Just remove the semicolon. That's all.

## [JS Bin](http://output.jsbin.com/gujomivoqa)

Comment: Nope. Not the problem

Comment: Show us your css, or your webpage, whatever.